# lifetime extension returning reference from function

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Is the following UB (undefined-behavior) ?
Is it really one level "too much" that `value` is now dangling and there is no lifetime extension done by the compiler/language rules?

```cpp
const int &get_value(const int &value) { return value; };
int main()
{
    const auto &value = get_value(5);
    printf("Value is: %d", value);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your second question seems to make it quite clear that you *know* the answer to the first; you just don't like it. So what do you really want to know?

Comment: @NicolBolas this is from a tweet discussion. Someone said it is "one level too much" and I dont understand why. It's not about liking it or not. I really want to improve my knowledge and I apologize if it is not phrased well. Can you please help me to rephrase it better so others can help? thank you in advance!

Comment: Sidenote: Right-gluing reference and pointer symbols makes it look like it's not a part of the type returned/created. It looks like dereferencing or taking the address of something. If you're coming from `C`, I get it, but for the sake of `C++` readability, try to get used to left-gluing.

Comment: @Kobi: "*I dont understand why.*" OK: what don't you understand about "why"? It's a function call, and those are the rules of how temporaries work in a function call. What more "why" does there need to be?

Comment: @NicolBolas - I'd like some help to identify the location in the standard that explains those rules. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is UB. When passing by `5` to `get_value()`, a temporary object is created and function parameter `const` reference `value` bind to it. Since, the temporary object bound to function parameter `value`, it will persist until the completion of the full expression containing the call. In the `main()`, you are dereferencing a reference which is not bound to a living object and this is undefined bahavior.